# Is there a way to handle overlapping keyword bracketing in Python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of keywords and an input string labelled section, I want my code to find those keywords within section and put them inside [] square brackets. However, my keywords sometimes overlap with each other.

`keywords = ["alpha", "alpha beta", "alpha beta charlie", "alpha beta charlie delta"]`

To fix that I sorted them by length so that the longer keywords would be prioritized.
However, when I run my code, sometimes I would get double or nested brackets (I assume it is because it still detects those as valid keywords)

I tried this:

```
import re

keywords = ["alpha", "alpha beta", "alpha beta charlie", "alpha beta charlie delta"]

keywords.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

section = "alpha alpha beta alpha beta charlie alpha beta charlie delta"
section = section.replace("'", "’").replace("\"", "”")
section_lines = section.split('\n')
for i, line in enumerate(section_lines):
    if not line.startswith('#'):
        section_lines[i] = re.sub(r'-',' ',line)
        for x in range(4):
            section_lines[i] = re.sub(r'\b' + f"{keywords[x]}" + r'\b', f"[{keywords[x]}]", section_lines[i], flags=re.IGNORECASE)
            section_lines[i] = section_lines[i].replace("[[", "[").replace("]]", "]")

section = '\n'.join(section_lines)
section = section.replace("   "," ").replace("  "," ")

print(section)
```

Do not mind the line splits, it is for another part of to handle multiple lines.

I wanted:
[alpha] [alpha beta] [alpha beta charlie] [alpha beta charlie delta]

but instead I got:
[alpha] [alpha] beta] [alpha] beta] charlie] [alpha] beta] charlie] delta]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join the sorted keywords into an alternation pattern instead of substituting the string with different keywords 4 times, each time potentially substituting the replacement string from the previous iteration:

```
import re

keywords = ["alpha", "alpha beta", "alpha beta charlie", "alpha beta charlie delta"]
keywords.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
section = "alpha alpha beta alpha beta charlie alpha beta charlie delta"
print(re.sub(rf"\b({'|'.join(keywords)})\b", r'[\1]', section))
```

This outpouts:

```
[alpha] [alpha beta] [alpha beta charlie] [alpha beta charlie delta]
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution here works for your specific example, *though it assumes* that the `section` **string you are working with is ordered from shortest slice to longest slice**.

My solution gets removes the biggest slice of the string, in this case `'alpha beta charlie delta'`, then the second biggest, and onwards. It appends these sections to a list, which I then sort by length, and lastly, add square braces to each element in the list as I add them to a string. Code below:

```
#Constants/inputs.
keywords = ["alpha", "alpha beta", "alpha beta charlie", "alpha beta charlie delta"]
keywords.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
section = "alpha alpha beta alpha beta charlie alpha beta charlie delta"

#Iterate and remove largest slices/keys and successively add to a list.
result_list = []
for keyword in keywords:
    remainder = section.split(keyword)[0]
    result_list.append(section[len(remainder):].strip())
    section = remainder

#Create the string from the result by ordering it by length and adding bracket characters.
result_string = ''
result_list.sort(key=len)
for element in result_list:
    result_string += '[' + element + ']'

print(result_string)
```

Comment: You can see this is wrong if you append the string `"alpha"` to the input `section`

Comment: Correct, this solution works for the very specific "section" he provided. For alternates, the remainder will have to be handled differently.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for maximum flexibility you could consider making a state machine.

*Warning, this is really going for the overkill award.*

I won't go into detail on state machines here, there's plenty of resources out there that would cover it much better than I would (here's [one that gives an example in Python](https://hackernoon.com/state-machines-can-help-you-solve-complex-programming-problems)). Still, here's a rough rundown of what's going on in the example below:

The most important thing to take a look at is `self.transitions`. This defines a dict of states. Each state has a collection of triggers that declares the next state and any actions that should be taken when transitioning to that state.

When `KeywordFinder.find_keywords()` is called, it iterates through each word in the input then uses that word to create a trigger. If that trigger exists in the current state then it moves to the next state and calls the action associated with that transition.

In short, this will allow you to handle more complex inputs. For example, compare the output of the following input using the state machine approach with the regex approach. You'll find that getting the right results with regex is pretty tricky.

`section = "alpha alpha beta alpha beta charlie alpha beta charlie delta beta charlie alpha alpha beta charlie alpha delta beta alpha charlie alpha beta charlie"`

Anyways, here's a working example:

```
import re

class KeywordFinder:
    KEYWORDS = [
        "alpha",
        "alpha beta",
        "alpha beta charlie",
        "alpha beta charlie delta"
    ]

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.state = 'search_for_start'
        self.transitions = {
            'search_for_start': {
                self.KEYWORDS[0]: {
                    'next_state': 'check_next_keyword',
                    'action': self.start_new_result
                },
            },
            'check_next_keyword': {
                True: {
                    'next_state': 'check_next_keyword',
                    'action': self.add_to_result
                },
                False: {
                    'next_state': 'search_for_start',
                    'action': self.end_result
                },
                self.KEYWORDS[0]: {
                    'next_state': 'check_next_keyword',
                    'action': self.start_new_result
                },
            },
        }
        self.next_keyword_idx = 0
        self.current_result = ''
        self.output = ''

    def find_keywords(self, search: str) -> str:
        words = search.split(" ")
        for word in words:
            self.handle_word(word)

        if self.current_result:
            self.end_result('')
            
        return self.output
    
    def handle_word(self, word: str) -> None:
        if self.state == 'check_next_keyword':
            trigger = self.is_next_keyword(word) if word != self.KEYWORDS[0] else word
        else:
            trigger = word

        if trigger not in self.transitions[self.state]:
            return
        
        action = self.transitions[self.state][trigger]['action']
        action(word)

        self.state = self.transitions[self.state][trigger]['next_state']

    def is_next_keyword(self, word: str) -> bool:
        try:
            is_next = f'{self.current_result} {word}' == self.KEYWORDS[self.next_keyword_idx]
        except IndexError:
            is_next = False

        return is_next
    
    def start_new_result(self, word: str) -> None:
        if len(self.current_result) > 0:
            self.end_result('')

        self.current_result = word
        self.next_keyword_idx = 1

    def add_to_result(self, word: str) -> None:
        self.current_result += f' {word}'
        self.next_keyword_idx += 1

    def end_result(self, word: str) -> None:
        self.current_result = f'[{self.current_result}]'
        if len(self.output) > 0:
            self.output += f' {self.current_result}'
        else:
            self.output = self.current_result

        self.current_result = ''
        self.next_keyword_idx = 0


# Fails with complex input
def regexSub(section: str) -> str:
    keywords = ["alpha", "alpha beta", "alpha beta charlie", "alpha beta charlie delta"]
    keywords.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

    return re.sub(rf"\b({'|'.join(keywords)})\b", r'[\1]', section)

def main() -> None:
    # section = "alpha alpha beta alpha beta charlie alpha beta charlie delta"
    section = "alpha alpha beta alpha beta charlie alpha beta charlie delta beta charlie alpha alpha beta charlie alpha delta beta alpha charlie alpha beta charlie"

    print("### Regex results ###")
    print(regexSub(section))
    # output: [alpha] [alpha beta] [alpha beta charlie] [alpha beta charlie delta] beta charlie [alpha] [alpha beta charlie] [alpha] delta beta [alpha] charlie [alpha beta charlie]

    print("\n### State machine results results ###")
    finder = KeywordFinder()
    print(finder.find_keywords(section))
    # output: [alpha] [alpha beta] [alpha beta charlie] [alpha beta charlie delta] [alpha] [alpha beta charlie] [alpha] [alpha] [alpha beta charlie]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```